# How to alert about kubernetes events repeating for too long?

Tags: kubernetes, events, monitoring, splunk

My task is to find when a Kubernetes [event](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/cluster-resources/event-v1/) is repeated for a long time, to alert us about it.
e.g. a Liveness probe fails way more than is reasonable due to a deployment restart (but this is just an example, the trigger for this task is a request to monitor any repeated error event)

We use [kubernetes-event-exporter](https://github.com/resmoio/kubernetes-event-exporter) to export events to Splunk, so we can query them there.

I found the `count` field in the exported events, e.g.:

```
$ kubectl get events -A -o json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "count": 1852,
            "eventTime": null,
            "firstTimestamp": "2023-11-06T23:56:55Z",
            "involvedObject": {
                "apiVersion": "v1",
                "fieldPath": "spec.containers{xxx}",
                "kind": "Pod",
                "name": "xxx-97cf7f9dc-922rb",
                "namespace": "some-namespace",
                "resourceVersion": "764541919",
                "uid": "6aded215-e148-4b54-94c7-ad5fd394f1aa"
            },
            "kind": "Event",
            "lastTimestamp": "2023-11-13T00:56:15Z",
            "message": "Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500",
            "metadata": {
                "creationTimestamp": "2023-11-09T18:28:15Z",
                "name": "xxxx-97cf7f9dc-922rb.17952e00cd9cfc38",
                "namespace": "some-namespace",
                "resourceVersion": "781477570",
                "uid": "9ca6c31e-8de9-4a48-a93d-8a74eeaa928b"
            },
            "reason": "Unhealthy",
            "reportingComponent": "",
            "reportingInstance": "",
            "source": {
                "component": "kubelet",
                "host": "ip-some-ip.some-region.compute.internal"
            },
            "type": "Warning"
        },
```

The "count" field in an event is described in [non-official references](https://www.weave.works/blog/understanding-kubernetes-events) as "Count(first and last timestamp): shows how much the event has repeated.".

In the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/cluster-resources/event-v1/) it's marked as deprecated (?).

We currently use Kubernetes 1.27 on EKS.

So the question is:

1. Does anyone know how can I query for K8s events which are repeated for longer than a certain threshold, so I can chart and preferably alert about them?
2. Is the `count` field relevant? How is it calculated (I mean - "repeated since when?" and should I rely on it since it could be deprecated?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

To alert about Kubernetes events repeating for too long, you can query for events with a count higher than a certain threshold over a specific time period. The count field in an event shows how many times the event has occurred since it was first generated

However, the count field is marked as deprecated in the official documentation, so it may not be reliable to use

Kubernetes events are short-lived and only available for one hour after they are generated

To get actionable insights from these events, you can use Grafana to chart them

To query for events with a count higher than a certain threshold, you can use kubectl to get events and filter them based on the count field. For example, you can use the following command to get events with a count higher than 10:

kubectl get events --all-namespaces --field-selector count>10

You can also use the --since and --until flags to specify a time range for the events

Once you have the events, you can chart them in Grafana and set up alerts based on the chart. For example, you can set up an alert to trigger when the count of a specific event is higher than a certain threshold for a certain amount of time

It's important to note that not all Kubernetes events are relevant for monitoring and alerting. Some events are purely for diagnostic purposes and are not used by Kubernetes controllers to trigger any behavior

Therefore, it's important to focus on the key performance indicators that directly affect system performance or user experience